# CSS Layout Issue Causing Horizontal Scroll

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

So, I imported a demo theme (wordpress). The theme came with some issues including a horizontal scroll that the developer is refusing to fix. I would like some assistance to explain how to remove the horizontal scroll or what is causing it so i find a way to fix it with CSS somehow.

site is located here - http://corporateh27.sg-host.com/

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (and in fact, all of the Stack Exchange Network) must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which require users to go off-site to get more information are not useful to future visitors, particularly once the off-site resource changes. This question might be good/useful, but you need to move enough code into the question so we know what you're asking without needing to go off-site to find out. Please see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428) for more details.

Comment: There is no horizontal scroll at all. Not sure which part you're talking about.

Comment: http://corporateh27.sg-host.com/portfolio/charlotte-blagawah/  -  this page for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you get horizontal scroll issues the best thing to do is put an `outline` on every element using:

```
* {outline: 1px solid blue;}
```

This then effectively adds a border to every element on the page (it is better to use the `outline` property as opposed to `border` because outline doesn't add any pixel values to the size of the elements the way `border` does).

You will then be able to see which element is causing the problem and fix it.

When you find the problematic element a lot of people tend to add `overflow: hidden;` on a parent element. Generally I would recommend finding the specific issue/child element causing the problem. In your case it is being caused by padding values added to an entire list of bootstrap classes. I've deselected them in the image. (see Image):

[image: Bootstrap padding values]

Instead of picking through all of those values, in your case it's probably worth just adding `.content {overflow:hidden}` which will remove overflow from the main `.content` class. Some of the code being used in that theme is woeful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Paul. I was hoping for a css line to fix the issue for me rather than making major changes.

Comment: because I don't know how the site has been made with elementor and what potential hidden elements are being used (which elementor sometimes does) in the backend all I can suggest is `.content {overflow:hidden}` It's a bit hacky but it will fix it.

Comment: I've done an edit to the answer but it's been closed now. The code snippet given will solve the issue and you can still accept the answer and upvote/mark as correct.

Comment: Well done paul. I added - .content {overflow:hidden} fixed it!